# Change google map css

Tags: google-maps

I have following code segment .

```
function initializeMap(nodeCoordinate) {
    $("#map-canvas").css('margin-left','50');
    var mapConstants = {
        'MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL': 2,
        'EMPTY_STRING': '',
        'INITIAL_LATITUDE': -25.463882,
        'INITIAL_LONGITUDE': 131.044922,
        'INDEX_ZERO': 0,
        'INDEX_ONE': 1
    }
    var myLatitudeLongitude = new google.maps.LatLng(mapConstants.INITIAL_LATITUDE, mapConstants.INITIAL_LONGITUDE);
    var activityCoordinate = nodeCoordinate.coordinate;
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: mapConstants.MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL,
        center: myLatitudeLongitude
    }
    var loadMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    jQuery.each(activityCoordinate, function (activityIndex, activityValue) {
        var activityAllCoordinate = activityValue.split(',');
        if (nodeCoordinate.coordinate != undefined && nodeCoordinate.coordinate != mapConstants.EMPTY_STRING) {
            myLatitudeLongitude = new google.maps.LatLng(activityAllCoordinate[mapConstants.INDEX_ZERO], activityAllCoordinate[mapConstants.INDEX_ONE]);
        } else {
            myLatitudeLongitude = new google.maps.LatLng(mapConstants.INITIAL_LATITUDE, mapConstants.INITIAL_LONGITUDE);
        }
        if (nodeCoordinate.coordinate != undefined && nodeCoordinate.coordinate != mapConstants.EMPTY_STRING) {
            var markerOnMap = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatitudeLongitude,
                map: loadMap,
                title: nodeCoordinate.label
            });
        }
    });
}
```

In above code I want to give margin-left css property to map .Please help me how can I give that . In line 2 I was trying to do this but using that line moves map container , but I am looking for moving map not the whole container .

Comment: Have you considered adding `padding-left:50px` to the container?

Comment: yes , but this moves the whole container and I am looking for moving map data only .

Comment: Are you trying to change the center of the map?

Comment: I actually want to scroll it horizontally from left .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("#map-canvas .gm-style").css('left', 50);
```

Or:

```
$("#map-canvas .gm-style").css('margin-left', 50);
```

But make sure to put it in last line before last curly bracket.

That's only a suggestion, because I really don't know what you're trying to achieve

Comment: thanks , it works for me . But at left of my map container map goes away means container at left looks void .

Comment: Maybe try just: `$("#map-canvas").css('margin-left', 50);` or show me on screenshot what you're trying to achieve